# Make [unity] a synonym of [ubuntu-unity]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request, tag-synonym-request

[unity](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/unity) (×21) refers both to:

- [ubuntu-unity](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu-unity) (×21), Ubuntu's new default desktop
- [vmware-unity](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/vmware-unity) (×12), a special display mode in VMware

I've already mapped all "unity" questions that belonged to VMware to [vmware-unity](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/vmware-unity). I also created the proper tag wikis. Given that the majority of [unity](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/unity) questions are and will be about [ubuntu-unity](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu-unity), I propose:

Create a synonym [unity](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/unity) ← [ubuntu-unity](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu-unity).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
updating post history, 27 rows affected
updating posts, 24 rows affected
updating PostTags associations, 18 rows affected
removing/renaming old tag, 0 rows affected
updating count for master tag, 1 rows affected
tag remapping of [ubuntu-unity] and [unity] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
3 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
Tag Synonym unity -> ubuntu-unity was approved!
```

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)!